# PHP DateTime Error| date_create() [function.date-create]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm having an issue with posting the date to my database the retrieving it when I reload the page. I want it to automatically timestamp the last entry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Location Tracker</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <hl> ACW Location Tracker </hl>

<?php
    $server = 'SQL2008.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk';

    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_531545");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
    $query='create table Location ';
    $query .= '(Username int NOT NULL IDENTITY(500, 23), First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL, Surname varchar(50) NOT NULL, Current_Location varchar(50) NOT NULL, Date datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Username))';
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$result)
    {
      if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null)
      {
         foreach( $errors as $error ) {
           echo "<p>Error: ".$error[ 'message']."</p>";
         }
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>DB successfully created</p>";
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);

    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"rde_531545");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO Location (First_Name, Surname, Current_Location, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?,? )";
    $params = array("John","Doe","Hull", Date);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query,$params);
    $params = array("Jane","Doe","Hull", Date);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query,$params);

    $LocationQuery='SELECT Username, First_Name, Surname, Current_Location, Date FROM Location';
    $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $LocationQuery);
    if ($results) while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
       echo '<p>'.$row['Username'].' '.$row['First_Name'].' '.$row['Surname'].' '.$row['Current_Location'].' '.$row['Date'].'</p>';
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Date - assumed 'Date' in
>   C:\RDEUsers\NET\531545\Location.php on line 44
>
> Warning: date_create() [function.date-create]: It is not safe to rely
>   on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of`enter code here` those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '0.0/no DST`enter code
>   here`' instead in C:\RDEUsers\NET\531545\Location.php on line 49
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in C:\RDEUsers\NET\531545\Location.php on line 51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a class `Date`, instead of sending a string '2017-02-03'.

the bug is in `$params = array(....., Date);`

in the second row from this slice of code:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO Location (First_Name, Surname, Current_Location, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?,? )";
$params = array("John","Doe","Hull", Date);
```

you need to create a Date object `$date =  new DateTime();`
and into the query, you need to extract the string from it, with `format` function:

```
$dateStr = $date->format(''Y-m-d H:i:s'');
```

then, use $dateStr in your params:     `$params = array("John","Doe","Hull", $dateStr);`

---

**EDIT 1:**

```
$date = new DateTime();
$dateStr = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$params = array("John","Doe","Hull", $dateStr);
```

Comment: Hi I've gone about trying to do that but I still don't quite understand what you mean, I've only just started learning this. Where exactly do I have to put this: $date =  new DateTime(); and $dateStr = $date->format(''Y-m-d H:i:s'');.

Comment: Do not put `Date` in your `$params`.
You should first create a `dateTime` object, then use it to get a date string by using the method `format`.

please look at the code i added in my answer under EDIT 1: